# Difference between Edgeshape.new and PolygonShape.new (box2d)

Tags: lua, box2d, gideros

In Gideros, which is a 2d game development engine, box2d is a physics library, which probably is external library and not internal to Lua, there are function called edgeshape.new and Polygonshape.new(), what is the difference between two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EdgeShape can only have 2 points, sort of like a line. [EdgeShape](http://docs.giderosmobile.com/reference/physics/b2EdgeShape/new), you can maybe use it as a floor, for example.

PolygonShape on the other hand, can have multiple points, like a triangle, box, and so on. [PolygonShape](http://docs.giderosmobile.com/reference/physics/b2PolygonShape#b2.PolygonShape)

Comment: So, that means I can possibly represent an edge shape by a polygon shape as well or is it a mandate that polygon represents more than plgon shape will work for more than two points only?